# 'allowing' vs. 'that allows'

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Is *an app allowing* or is *an app that allows* correct?

> XXX is **an app that allows** parents to monitor and restrict their children's food intake from the school canteen.

OR

> XXX is **an app allowing** parents to monitor and restrict their children's food intake from the school canteen.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. Your choice (both are *allowable*) depends on your style of writing.

Here, your use of "*the school canteen*" makes this style very informal.

Among the possibilities are

> allow, permit, enables, provide, let, etc.

The least formal of these is ***let***.

In accordance with your very informal style, you might consider using **lets** instead of **allows**. It's edgier, as is your use of the word *canteen*.

> XXX is an app **that lets** parents monitor and restrict their children's food intake from the school canteen.

Answer (score 0):

Both work just fine. But I would use "an app allowing" because it is more formal.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them, there are "permissions"

The function phrase "that allows" is used so if means

"Something that you permit"

Other words after the word "that", let, provide, enable, etc.

An example

> Here we used the app **that allows** us to listen music

But there's only one misspelling the word "allowing"  but there's no find an permission, you misspelled

Here's a misspelled example

> Here we used the app **allowing** us to listen music